# set a particular option in a select box using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm unable to perform the desired event.

```
  <?php
    include_once 'includes/db.php';
        $result = mysql_query('SELECT country,code FROM countries') or die(mysql_error());

        echo '<select id="CountryCode">';
        echo '<option value="Select">Select</option>';
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
           echo '<option value=$row["country"]>'.$row['country'].'</option>';
        }
        echo '<option value="Other">Other</option>';
        echo '</select>';
    ?>
<input id="country" type="hidden" value="IN"/>
<script>
$(function() 
{
$('#CountryCode').val($('#country').val());
});
</script>
```

Everything works fine. But the desired item is not selected in the select box

Comment: What is your specific question? They usually end with a `?` ;-) Also I highly recommend you thoroughly read [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) - paying special attention to parts concerning the use of array keys directly in strings. If you inspect the HTML source code that this produces, I suspect you will find that "Everything works fine" is not correct. In fact, I think that is actually the root cause of your problem.

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Comment: my html source code do not contain the select values generated by php script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the Attribute "selected" of the option to "selected". Try this (untested):

```
$("#CountryCode").val($('#country').val()).attr('selected','selected');
```

Answer (score 0):

The `echo` in your `while()` loop should look like this:

```
echo '<option value="'.$row["country"].'">'.$row['country'].'</option>';
```

Your string above was printing a literal `$row["country"]` instead of the value that it contained.